# Angular Elements bug when using in Angular6 app

Tags: angular, web-component, zonejs, zone.js, angular-elements

I'm facing a strange behavior using Angular Elements to build a widget. I have created a widget to pop-up a simple feedback form on another site, build with Angular too, and work pretty well in development, but when I build the application for production, there are incompatibilities between the widget and some lazy loaded modules.

The widget is loaded into the application from an external URL when application first load. Then I log in to the application and when a module is lazy loaded, it reports the following error

Some contextual info:

- The widget is build using "@angular/elements": "^7.0.1"
- The widget is using a pollyfill cause Web components is not broad adopted yet.
- The pollyfills uses Zone.js
- The app is build using Angular 7.0.1

Digging into this fuzzy error message I figure out that this was related with Zone.js loaded twice by the app and the widget, this are issues related with this 
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24466 
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24181
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26158

```
Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
    at polyfills.d19af636bcf00eb4898f.js:1
    at polyfills.d19af636bcf00eb4898f.js:1
    at Object.0TWp (polyfills.d19af636bcf00eb4898f.js:1)
    at a (runtime.f35a2a91d37680127d85.js:1)
    at Module.hN/g (polyfills.d19af636bcf00eb4898f.js:1)
    at a (runtime.f35a2a91d37680127d85.js:1)
    at Object.1 (polyfills.d19af636bcf00eb4898f.js:1)
    at a (runtime.f35a2a91d37680127d85.js:1)
    at r (runtime.f35a2a91d37680127d85.js:1)
    at Array.t [as push] (runtime.f35a2a91d37680127d85.js:1)
```

I have try out this solution also, without success:
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/elements-zone-strategy

I'm new to Angular Elements, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your angular element doesn't need zone.js. You can follow this post on removing the zone.js dependency and taking care of the side effects.
https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/06/angular-elements-without-zone-js.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is already been fixed in `zone.js`, but not released yet, https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/1121, please wait for the next release of zone.js